# Failed to install when creating project in rails because of sqlite3 in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to create a project in rails in Windows, the problem seems to be sqlite3, and download the DLLs and paste them into the root folders of the system, also download the snapshot of sqlite3, which comes with C files, also download the
  precompiler windows files, all the previous ones also paste them in Ruby's Bin folder, and it does not work.
This is the error that appears to me:

```
Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190206-6188-kcs4ky.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include

        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
inspection.

Results logged to

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:

sqlite3
```

Check the file mkmf.log that tells me in the error, and I do not have anything clear either, I get the following error

Everything seems to indicate that the sqlite3.h file was not found, but I pasted it in ruby's bin folder, as I said before.

My question is, how can I solve this error? It should be noted that you download everything from the RubyInstaller page.

```
package configuration for sqlite3 is not found
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

**Update**

I no longer see the previous error, I manage to solve it, however now I get the following error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-dir=C:\sqlite3'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190206-18620-1k9ev7e.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir=C:\sqlite3
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1144:in `block in find_header'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1143:in `find_header'
        from extconf.rb:64:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I give up, with sqlite3 it is impossible to make it work, it s one after another error.
The final solution after a dozen errors is to create the project with postgresql, install postgresql in Windows, and then create the project, and configure the database.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this works with me:

Add `gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"` into Gemfile

and then run `bundle install`